# jquery add class and remove class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to make .s button
when click on .s button
will be append new  element into  tag
and remove .s class and add new class .h
when click on .h class, <[style]> element remove from my body

I want when click .s add <[style]> element and when click on .h remove <[style]> element

add class "h" is working good! but when click .h <[style]> element not remove!!

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {

        var style = '<style class="kha">body{background:#000;}</style>'

        jQuery(".s").click( function () { 
            jQuery("body").append(style);
            jQuery(".s").addClass("h").removeClass("s");
        });

        jQuery(".h").click(function () { 
            jQuery(".kha").remove();
        });

    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <span class="s">Black Color</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.toggleClass()`:

```js
var style = '<style class="kha">body{background:#000;}</style>';
jQuery(".s").click(function() {
  jQuery("body").append(style); // append the style
  if($(this).hasClass('h')){$('.kha').remove();} // check if class h is added 
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("s h"); // toggle the class to .s .h
});
```

```css
.s {
  color: green;
}
.h {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='s'>s with h toggle.</div>
```

Comment: yeah working but [style] element not removed! i want to remove style element when click on .h and when click on .s add style element, look to style va.

Comment: @Sultan you can put your styles in a specific order first s then h.

Comment: work but background color not removing i want when click .s add style va into body and when click .h remove style var from body, i have a long style but i patse body background color for example only

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4b8jzs76/)

```
$("#addClass").click(function () {

    $('#para1').addClass('highlight');

});

$("#removeClass").click(function () {

    $('#para1').removeClass('highlight');

});
```

Comment: delegation for style??